# SOAPUI - xpath engine/parser seems that arthmetic operations do not works there

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, soapui

I have following problem.

I am sending SOAP request and after getting response I need to "Get Data" from it, add "1" and send back as another SOAP request.

My SOAP response to analyze is like that:

```
<multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" >
         <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">basketId</name>
         <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">12</value>
      </multiRef>
```

I want to get that 12 and add 1 to it: I do it in SOAP UI by XPATH inserted in new request (I do not want to use anything else). Pure XML of new request looks like that:

```
<multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" >
    <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">basketId</name>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">${GetBasketID_3#Response#//multiRef[name="newBasketId"]/value/text() +1 }</value>
</multiRef>
```

the xpath expression is:

```
//multiRef[name="newBasketId"]/value/text() + 1
```

With xpathchecker in Firefox this works, but SOAP UI sends empty value there.
How can I make push SOAP UI xpath parser to work or write xpath expression in working way?

Comment: Isn't the `name` equal to `'basketId'` instead of `'newBasketId'`?

Comment: Please, provide the complete XML document. It is likely there is a default namespace there and this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the entire XML, it will be easier to provide the exact answer. However you can try the below xpath. The problem can be related with the missing namespace .

```
${Test Request#Response#declare namespace ns1='http://ADDNAMESPACEHERE'; //multiRef[1]/value[1]/text()}
```